# How to render a heatmap for a large array

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a large dataset from which I derive a squared matrix I would like to visualize as a heatmap. I'm using Matplotlib and Seaborn. Unfortunately, it seems to work only for a relatively small amount of data.

```
        size = 10000
        similarity_matrix = np.random.rand(size, size)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.heatmap(similarity_matrix, vmin=0, vmax=1)

        plt.savefig("matrix.png")
```

This stops working from approximately `size=6000`, resulting in a white heatmap.

[image: Heatmap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The original code didn't generate a plot for me
- Changing `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` to `plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))`, worked to create the plot.

  - At `figsize=(10, 10)`, the figure didn't render in Jupyter, but the correct image did save to a file.
  - A figure smaller than `figsize=(14, 14)`, wouldn't render in Jupyter.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create matrix
size = 10000
similarity_matrix = np.random.rand(size, size)

# plot matrix

# create figure and set size
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))

# add heatmap
sns.heatmap(similarity_matrix, vmin=0, vmax=1)

# save the figure
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=600)

# show the figure; this was slow
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`imshow` or `matshow` seems to work fine:

```
np.random.seed(42)
size = 10000
similarity_matrix = np.random.rand(size, size)
plt.imshow(similarity_matrix, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
```

Output:

[image]